Parallel for_each without container with non-constexpr std::views::iota
I'm looking for a replacement for
std::vector<double> data(n, 0);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
  data[i] = func(i);
}

which can be called with std::transform with a parallel execution policy like this:
std::vector<double> data(n, 0);
std::transform(
      std::execution::par_unseq,
      /*from 0*/,
      /*to n*/,
      data.begin(),
      func);

I want to achieve the same thing as in this question here. But instead of calling std::views::iota with constexpr values, I want to call it using runtime values.
My current solution looks like this:
std::vector<size_t> indexes(n, 0);
auto indexFillFunc = [&indexes](const size_t &value){
    return &value - &indexes[0];
};

std::transform(
  std::execution::par_unseq,
  indexes.begin(),
  indexes.end(),
  indexes.begin(),
  indexFillFunc);

std::vector<double> data(n, 0);
std::transform(
  std::execution::par_unseq,
  indexes.begin(),
  indexes.end(),
  data.begin(),
  func);

But it isn't good because I still need to save the indexes into a vector and iterate over the vector. I could get the index from the data vector using the same method as in the indexFillFunc but for future purposes I'd like to know how to achieve this normally.

What's wrong with std::ranges::views::iota(0, n);?

It doesn't compile for me but I think I found the issue. 0 is interpreted automatically as an integer and I was passing in a size_t for n. And it was this that blocked me from compiling. If I have this: std::ranges::views::iota((size_t)0, (size_t)n) then it works now.

Thanks for the help, I thought I was going crazy.
